# Need to map classes to different databases at runtime in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mapping

I have `MainDB` database and unknown number (at compile time) of `UserDB_1`, ..., `UserDB_N` databases. `MainDB` contains names of those `UserDB` databases in some table (new `UserDB` can be created at runtime).

All `UserDB` have exactly the same table names and fields.

How to handle such situation in Hibernate? (database structure cannot be changed).

Currently I am planning to create generic `User` classes not mapped to anything and just use native SQL for all queries:

```
session.createSQLQuery("select * from " + db + ".user where id=1")
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));
```

Is there anything better I can do? Ideally I would want to have mappings for UserDB tables and relations and use HQL on required database.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the database when building your `SessionFactory` (via the connection string of the `DataSource`). When you want to use another database, simply rebuild the `SessionFactory` with the new `DataSource`.

Comment: Could you please show how to rebuild it? Wouldn't it affect the whole application? I need to switch to another database only temporary for specific queries. And how do I map user tables? I need to provide some table names for mapping but user databases might not exist at compile time, so I can't map them to anything specific.

Comment: Also I am using Spring, so this SessionFactory is initialized in config file and wrapped inside TransactionManager.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and inject different `SessionFactory` (one per database).

Answer (score 0):

Read this article on Hibernate blog: http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/MultitenancyInHibernate

Steve says that it is better to use a ConnectionProvider than separate SessionFactory.

Remember to disable second level cache.